# HTTP Error 500.30 Azure.RequestFailedException

Tags: azure, visual-studio, asp.net-core, azure-keyvault

I used Visual Studio 4.8.04084 to push my app to Azure App Services. I have configured my connections for

- Azure App Configuration
- Azure Key Vault
- Azure SQL Database: my data
- Azure SQL Database: identity service
- Azure Storage
- Secrets.json

When I run the app through the Kestrel service locally, everything performs fine. However, when I run it through IIS I get the following issues:

Visual Studio exception message:

> Exception thrown: 'Azure.RequestFailedException' in Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration.dll
>
> Exception thrown: 'Azure.RequestFailedException' in Navrae.WebApp.dll
>
> An exception of type 'Azure.RequestFailedException' occurred in Navrae.WebApp.dll but was not handled in user code.
> Service request failed.
> Status: 403 (Forbidden)
>
> Headers:
> Server: openresty/1.17.8.2
> Date: Wed, 31 Mar 2021 15:39:42 GMT
> Connection: keep-alive
> x-ms-request-id: 09275563-49a0-40e6-88e2-**** (dotting these out just in case)
> x-ms-client-request-id: 9adcfd53-1a94-43df-aac8-**** (dotting these out just in case)
> x-ms-correlation-request-id: 09275563-49a0-40e6-88e2-**** (dotting these out just in case)
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
> Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
> Access-Control-Expose-Headers: DNT, X-CustomHeader, Keep-Alive, User-Agent, X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, Cache-Control, Content-Type, Authorization, x-ms-client-request-id, x-ms-useragent, x-ms-content-sha256, x-ms-date, host, Accept, Accept-Datetime, Date, If-Match, If-None-Match, Sync-Token, x-ms-return-client-request-id, ETag, Last-Modified, Link, Memento-Datetime, retry-after-ms, x-ms-request-id, x-ms-client-session-id, x-ms-effective-locale, WWW-Authenticate
> Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains
> Content-Length: 0
>
> 'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\x64\Runtime\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.NetCoreApp.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>
> The program '[22720] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).

Azure App Service log:

```
at Azure.Data.AppConfiguration.ConfigurationClient.d__42.MoveNext() at
 System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at 
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at
 Azure.Core.PageResponseEnumerator.FuncAsyncPageable`1.d__2.MoveNext() at 
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at 
System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.ManualResetValueTaskSourceCore`1.GetResult(Int16 token) at 
Azure.Core.PageResponseEnumerator.FuncAsyncPageable`1.d__2.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token) at Azure.AsyncPageable`1.d__6.MoveNext() at 
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at Azure.AsyncPageable`1.d__6.MoveNext() at 
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at 
System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.ManualResetValueTaskSourceCore`1.GetResult(Int16 token) at 
Azure.AsyncPageable`1.d__6.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token) at 
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration.AzureAppConfigurationProvider.<>c__DisplayClass20_1.<b__2>d.MoveNext() at
 System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at 
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration.AzureAppConfigurationProvider.<>c__DisplayClass20_1.<b__2>d.MoveNext() at 
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at 
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at 
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at 
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult() at 
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration.TracingUtils.d__2.MoveNext() at 
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at 
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at 
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at 
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult() at 
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration.AzureAppConfigurationProvider.d__28.MoveNext() at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at 
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at 
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at 
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration.AzureAppConfigurationProvider.d__20.MoveNext() at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at 
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at 
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at 
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult() at 
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration.AzureAppConfigurationProvider.Load() at 
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationRoot..ctor(IList`1 providers) at 
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build() at 
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.BuildAppConfiguration() at
 Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build() at Navrae.WebApp.Program.d__0.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Work Laptop\source\repos\Navrae\Navrae.WebApp\Program.cs:line 19
```

**Azure log link message***

```
{"error":{"code":"AuthenticationFailed","message":"Authentication failed. The 'Authorization' header is missing."}}
```

When I debug the application it basically fails at CreateHostBuilder. None of my ConnectionStrings are populating and I don't know where or how to debug it further.

**CreateHostBuilder**

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
                {
                    var azConfigSettings = config.Build();
                    var azConfigConnection = azConfigSettings.GetConnectionString("REMOVED");
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(azConfigConnection))
                    {
                        // Use the connection string if it is available.
                        config.AddAzureAppConfiguration(azConfigConnection);
                    }
                    else if (Uri.TryCreate(azConfigSettings["Endpoints:REMOVED"], UriKind.Absolute, out var endpoint))
                    {
                        // Use Azure Active Directory authentication.
                        config.AddAzureAppConfiguration(options =>
                        {
                            options.Connect(endpoint, new DefaultAzureCredential());
                        });
                    }
                    var keyVaultEndpoint = new Uri(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("REMOVED")!);
                    config.AddAzureKeyVault(
                    keyVaultEndpoint,
                    new DefaultAzureCredential());
                })
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
```

Answer (score 2):

The error you are getting is HTTP 403 Forbidden.

What is probably happening is that:

- when you run locally you are using your identity that has access to the Azure services.
- when you run in IIS you are using the network service identity that does not have access to the Azure services.

In Azure App Services you can configure it to run as a "managed identity", you can then give that managed identity access to the services you are using.

Comment: So I wiped everything and I'm implementing small changes to see where it's broken. I had it set to managed identity with permissions given. I tried turning that off but no resolve. I'm going to look for some tutorials on how to add it all manually since I'm still new to coding and practically new to azure.

Comment: It looks like you are using 5 services that all need permisions granted to the managed identity. If it stil does not work maybe you missed one.

Comment: I'm having a very similar issue (403, malformed headers), did you get it resolved?